# In AngularJS, my directive can't access $scope properties of the parent controler defined in $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-http

I'm creating a custom directive that inherits the scope of the parent controller. For the most part, I can access the directive's "scope" object that I set in the controller's "$scope" except for properties I set inside an $http.get. Whether those properties came from the API or were just literally defined does not matter.

What's very weird to me is that if I just log the directive's "scope" I can definitely see the properties set by $http.get, but if I try to access them directly they are undefined.

I can access everything in the HTML view perfectly.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

myApp.controller('getData', function($scope, $http) {
  var myData='myData.json';
  $scope.helloFromController = "Hello! This is the controller!";
  $scope.getTheData = function() {
    $http.get(myData).
      success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.helloFromHttp = "Hello! This is the http!";
      });
  };
  $scope.getTheData();
});

myApp.directive('useData', function ($parse) {
  var directiveObj = {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(scope); 
        // Returns the scope object that clearly includes the helloFromController and helloFromControllerHttp properties
      console.log(scope.helloFromController); 
        // returns "Hello! This is the controller!"
      console.log(scope.helloFromHttp) 
        // returns undefined
    } 
  };
  return directiveObj;
});
```

It looks like there's something about how $scope works with $http that I don't understand. Help is appreciated.

Comment: It's not about $scope, it's just the fact that ajax is asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

The linking function executes before the callback from the asynchronous http call gets invoked.

Sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/k54ubb9L/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" use-data>
  Hello, {{ userData.username }}!
</div>


var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  function getTheData() {
    $http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1").
    success(function(response, status) {
      $scope.userData = response;
    });
  };

  getTheData();
});

myApp.directive('useData', function($parse) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch("userData", function(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log(newValue, oldValue);
      });
    },
    restrict: "A"
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your directive is sharing the same scope of the controller. Your directive's link function loads when the directive is found in your template. `$scope.helloFromController` is just a string. So, you are seeing this by logging in console. But, `$scope.helloFromHttp` is set after the promise is resolved for `$http`. So, you don't see the value instantly as `console.log(scope.helloFromHttp)` before it is set in the controller. You can try using $timeout to see the changed value of `scope.helloFromHttp`.

```
myApp.directive('useData', function ($parse, $timeout) {
  var directiveObj = {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      // Returns the scope object that clearly includes the helloFromController and helloFromControllerHttp properties
      console.log(scope); 

      // returns "Hello! This is the controller!"  
      console.log(scope.helloFromController); 

      // returns undefined
      console.log(scope.helloFromHttp) 

      // set $timeout to trigger after 10 sec, you can reduce or increase the time
      $timeout(function() {
        console.log(scope.helloFromHttp); 
      }, 10000)
    } 
  };
  return directiveObj;
});
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: So this works, but it seems like bad practice. Is there a more sensible way to bind data from a $http.get into a directive?

Comment: As I said, `scope.helloFromHttp` in directive scope will get updated as directive scope is same as controller scope. There is nothing to do with the binding. But yes, if you want to do something in the directive link function after `scope.helloFromHttp` is updated via `$http`, you can  `$watch` the variable in directive link function.

Comment: That's actually what I just did. I used a $watch" and included a conditional to see if scope.helloFromHttp existed. That works perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code works fine without any changes; the problem is that you displayed it in the console, but if you display it in HTML, it gets refresh as expected. Here's the example: http://plnkr.co/edit/WrqO7FeF5d5JdVas9jiL?p=preview

```
directive('useData', function($parse) {
  return {
    template: "From directive: {{helloFromHttp}}",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      console.log(scope);
      // Returns the scope object that clearly includes the helloFromController and helloFromControllerHttp properties
      console.log(scope.helloFromController);
      // returns "Hello! This is the controller!"
      console.log(scope.helloFromHttp);
      // returns undefined
    }
  };
});
```